# Cannot open database 'x' requested by login when trying to connect to remote DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, webforms

When trying to connect to remote DB, I get this error in my code.

> underlying provider failed to open. Cannot open database 'x' requested
> by login. LOGIN FAILED FOR USER "<My local user(DESKTOP-E5KPAPG\localUser). NOT the user I have on sql server>"

I can log in using SSMS by providing credentials : Server Name : 111.11.111.111 and SQL Server Authentication - username and password : "userX", "p@ss";

In my code, connection string looks like this

```
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Connection Timeout=60; Data Source=111.11.111.111; Initial Catalog=x; User Id=userX; pwd=p@ss; Persist Security Info=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <add name="XEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.XModel.csdl|res://*/Model.XModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.XModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=111.11.111.111;initial catalog=x;persist security info=True;user id=userX;password=p@ss;connect timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

'p@ss' is my SQL Login password.
Also, providing sensitive details in connection string doesn't seem secure and is there a better alternative?

Comment: From the error message it looks like your connection is being made with Windows Auth.
Are you sure that these connection strings get used by the code? Something, somewhere in the code changes your settings?
Are there multiple instances on the remote host? Different ports?
A bit more details about your setup might help figuring it out.

Comment: Never assume! You always need a mechanism to see the actual connection string used when a connection fails. Do not assume that your application used the value in your config file.